# Touchpad left-click not working - Linux Mint on Dell Vostro 3640

Tags: linux, mouse, linux-mint, touchpad, dell-vostro

This is a question on behalf of my friend, so it might take me a little while to run tests and stuff.

The problem is that periodically her touchpad won't left click, either by pressing the physical left button or by tapping the touchpad. The right click button and mouse movement work just fine. The problem seems to come without any particular cause and lasts until she restarts.

I ran xinput test  and even whilst the LMB didn't appear to be doing anything, it was registering press and release signals appropriately, so I guess it's not a problem with the mouse drivers(?). Anyone have any ideas why this might be?

She's running a new install of Mint based on Ubuntu 13.10.

Thanks,

Kyle

Edit: One more thing, apparently she also experiences random left-clicking at the cursor, without pressing the buttons.

Comment: Sounds like a hardware problem.  This behavior new or old?

Comment: It's new, but has been going on as long as she has had Mint. Also, surely a hardware problem would mean that xinput test wouldn't report the clicking?